# PySide with PyQwt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qwt

I have a app that using PyQt/PyQwt, now I want to transform the PyQt to PySide but I don't know if PyQwt can work with PySide, it seems PyQwt is binded with PyQt. So is there a way that allow me to use PyQwt under the framework by PySide？

Comment: Check this link: https://gitorious.org/pysideqwt

Comment: thanks, but this project seems to be silent for a long time. @Carlangueitor

Comment: You may use **pyqtgraph**, it supports both pyqt and pyside